# Anyone knows how to round out objects like this?

Tags: modeling, video, shortcut

Anyone knows how to round out that cube at this video from 10:11
i really looked every where but since i am new here i couldn't find anything.
would really appreciate that.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0jwgvOwowuk&t=10s

Comment: The basic rounding is just done with the subdivision surface modifier. Right side of his screen. Just make sure Catmul-Clark is enabled instead of Simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to Sphere. Edit Mode.

[image]

Cube with high vertex density.  After To Sphere operation it looks like ... well a sphere.

<kbd>Shift Alt S</kbd>

The move your mouse away and experiment.